# UWP - From Json string to Structure (Classes)

Tags: json, uwp

I receive a JSon string from WS.  It's so long that I can't use Json2charp to parse it and receive the structurated class.

I want to parse the string with a command.  How is it possible?

I don't know the classes so I can't use a command like:

```
Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyClass.RootObject)(String_From_File)
```

Is it possible from the string to obtain the class without using json2charp site ?
For example, in vs.net if on the variable 'string_from_file' I choose  'Json Visualizer' and see all classes and data in correct mode.

How can I obtain the same in my code ?

I have installed Newtonsoft.json

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use the json to class mappers like NewtonSoft.Json. You can use the [Windows.Data.Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json.aspx) api. It let you parse and extract the data you want from your JSON string.

```
JsonValue jsonValue = JsonValue.Parse("{\"Width\": 800, \"Height\": 600, \"Title\": \"View from 15th Floor\", \"IDs\": [116, 943, 234, 38793]}");
double width = jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedNumber("Width");
double height = jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedNumber("Height");
string title = jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedString("Title");
JsonArray ids = jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedArray("IDs");
```

You can find a sample in the [Windows Universal Sample GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Json).

A complex object parsing is shown [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Json/cs/User.cs). I've extracted the most relevant parts here. The JSON string is provided to the `User` constructor which is extracting what it needs and then delegating the parsing to the nested `School` constructor.

```
{
  "id": "1146217767",
  "phone": null,
  "name": "Satya Nadella",
  "education": [
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "204165836287254",
        "name": "Contoso High School"
      },
      "type": "High School"
    },
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "116138758396662",
        "name": "Contoso University"
      },
      "type": "College"
    }
  ],
  "timezone": -8,
  "verified": true
}
```

This JSON fragment is parsed with this code:

```
    public User(string jsonString) : this()
    {
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonString);
        Id = jsonObject.GetNamedString(idKey, "");

        IJsonValue phoneJsonValue = jsonObject.GetNamedValue(phoneKey);
        if (phoneJsonValue.ValueType == JsonValueType.Null)
        {
            Phone = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Phone = phoneJsonValue.GetString();
        }

        Name = jsonObject.GetNamedString(nameKey, "");
        Timezone = jsonObject.GetNamedNumber(timezoneKey, 0);
        Verified = jsonObject.GetNamedBoolean(verifiedKey, false);

        foreach (IJsonValue jsonValue in jsonObject.GetNamedArray(educationKey, new JsonArray()))
        {
            if (jsonValue.ValueType == JsonValueType.Object)
            {
                Education.Add(new School(jsonValue.GetObject()));
            }
        }
    }

    public School(JsonObject jsonObject)
    {
        JsonObject schoolObject = jsonObject.GetNamedObject(schoolKey, null);
        if (schoolObject != null)
        {
            Id = schoolObject.GetNamedString(idKey, "");
            Name = schoolObject.GetNamedString(nameKey, "");
        }
        Type = jsonObject.GetNamedString(typeKey);
    }
```

If you cannot use the automatic mapping from NewtonSoft.Json, you have no other way than doing it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Is not so simple.
The Json i received is very complicated and have many class
So i can't use
double width = jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedNumber("Width");

[Inside class i have more ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2dT7.jpg)